# Pointers to objects in a std::vector corrupting after using push_back on the vector

Tags: c++, vector

In main.cpp, I have a vector of Entities:

```
std::vector<Entity> entities = {};
```

And each entity has a pointer to another entity (its target):

```
Entity* target = nullptr;
```

The entity gets a picks a random enemy from the vector passed as a reference:

entity.hpp:

```
void Entity::update(std::vector<Entity> &entities){

    // new target if no target
    if (target == nullptr){

        if (entities.size() > 1){

            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> index_dist(0, entities.size() - 1);
            
            while (true){
                target = &(entities.at(index_dist(rand_generator)));

                if (!isSameEntity(target)){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    if (target != nullptr){

        // move towards target
        float dist_x = (x + radius) - (target->x + target->radius);
        float dist_y = (y + radius) - (target->y + target->radius);
        float distance = sqrt(pow(dist_x, 2) + pow(dist_y, 2));
        if (abs(distance - (radius + target->radius)) > 1){
            std::cout << id << "=>" << target->id << "\n";
            float rad = radians(angle(x, y, target->x, target->y));
            float x_vel = sin(rad);
            float y_vel = cos(rad);
            // std::cout << "targ: " << id << "->" << target->id << "    " << target->x << "|" << target->y << "\n";
            x += x_vel;
            y += y_vel;
        }

        // try to attack target

        // check if target is dead
        if (target->health <= 0){
            target = nullptr;
        }

    }
    
    // render
    rect = {int(x), int(y), radius * 2, radius * 2};
    centerRect(rect);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
        entities.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                entities.begin(), entities.end(),
                [&entities](Entity &entity){
                    entity.update(entities);
                    return entity.health <= 0;
                }
            ),
            entities.end()
        );
```

And when I add a new entity to the vector, some of the target ids become a random large integer like 2127259440 (an entity's id should be 1 more than the last entity's id).

When I don't push_back a new entity to the vector, everything runs fine, but when I add a few more entities to the vector using push_back, some target ids go haywire.

Comment: Vectors will copy contents as they grow to new vectors so if any objects have pointers to other objects in the vector they will no longer be valid. You can use `reserve()` to preallocate vector space to fix that but it's bad practice to have pointers referring to other objects generally. If you do make sure the objects are never moved.

Comment: From a good reference on [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back): _"If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated."_

Comment: It looks like you're using a reference to a vector<Entity>. As you push new values, the vector may move to another area in memory that can accommodate the new size of the vector. You can fix this by using reserve() which will force the vector sie to be at least n (you'll also get an error if the size you're requesting to push_back is larger than n.

Comment: Yup thanks guys, I used an unordered map instead to keep track of which Entity I was using.